# (jQuery) Multiple split auto href not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will add in the automatic ID selector A, but could not for more than one selector.
I created the code like this:

```
<div class="comment_name"><a id="testing" href="http://test.wordpress.com">Djohan</a></div>
<div class="comment_name"><a id="testing" href="http://test.blogspot.com">Yogi</a></div>

<script>
var ksDOM=document.getElementById('testing').href;
var sprit=ksDOM.split(".")[1]
$(".comment_name a").attr("href",sprit);
</script>
```

Please help me. Below is an example of the full code:
http://www.kangsigit.com/p/editor.html?filename=not_work

Comment: IDs are made to only use once per page, i'd recommend to use classes for this

Comment: @Hendry *once per page* : )

Comment: @DelightedD0D thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs should be unique. You can rather use same class name and then class selector to target them. Also you can use callback function of `.attr()` to set new attribute value:

```js
$(".comment_name a").attr('href',function(e){
    return $(this).attr('href').split(".")[1];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment_name"><a id="testing_1" href="http://test.wordpress.com">Djohan</a></div>
<div class="comment_name"><a id="testing_2" href="http://test.blogspot.com">Yogi</a></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I could solve this problem :)